# Understanding options for kwargs in Python functions API

Tags: python, documentation

How do I know all the options for arguments of a function when there is a kwargs argument?  I've encountered this many times where the documentation isn't specific enough with respect to what they are.  I've never been able to figure out whether this is just lackluster documentation or there is a concept that I'm ignorant about.

For example, examine the following code from the HuggingFace [tutorial](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/llm_tutorial) on generation:

```
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM

model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    "openlm-research/open_llama_7b", device_map="auto", load_in_4bit=True
)
```

If we navigate to the [API](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/en/model_doc/auto#transformers.AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained), we see that there isn't a load_in_4bit argument, so this must be an optional keyword argument.  Here are the kwargs details:

```
kwargs (additional keyword arguments, optional) — Will be passed to the Tokenizer __init__() method. Can be used to set special tokens like bos_token, eos_token, unk_token, sep_token, pad_token, cls_token, mask_token, additional_special_tokens. See parameters in the __init__() for more details.
```

If I navigate to the Tokenizer **init** documentation like the above suggests, then I also see a keyword argument:

```
 |  __init__(self, vocab_file=None, merges_file=None, tokenizer_file=None, unk_token='<|endoftext|>', bos_token='<|endoftext|>', eos_token='<|endoftext|>', add_prefix_space=False, **kwargs)
 |      Initialize self.  See help(type(self)) for accurate signature.
```

So in this particular case, the only way I would have known about this argument is from the tutorial referenced, which is a very fragile way of understanding how to use a particular function.

Comment: Welcome to the world of bad documentation.  If this keyword argument isn't documented, then either it's poorly written documentation and you should complain (or fix the documentation yourself), or alternatively, you're not supposed to be using this keyword and it was purposely left out.

No, there is no good way for you to find out.

Comment: When the documentation says that the keyword arguments will be passed to something else, you need to look at its documentation. That way they don't need to repeat the documentation, and when the arguments to "something else" change they don't have to update their documentation.